# Balls are catched by bounds and they stick together (incorrect algorithm in draw method)

Tags: python, pygame

Let's consider following code (balls with random centers and velocities collide, with screen surface bounds, and with each other):

```
import pygame,sys,math
from pygame.locals import *
from random import randrange


WIDTH = 500
HEIGHT = 500
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
RADIUS = 10
FPS = 30
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT),0,32)
TAB = []

fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.display.set_caption('Animation')


class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def distance(self, A):
        return math.sqrt((A.x-self.x)**2 + (A.y-self.y)**2)
    def getTouple(self):
        return (self.x,self.y)

class Vector:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def norm(self):
        return math.sqrt(self.x**2 + self.y**2)

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, center, radius, velocity):
        self.center = center
        self.radius = radius
        self.velocity = velocity

    def __init__(self):
        self.radius = RADIUS
        self.center = Point(randrange(RADIUS,WIDTH-RADIUS), randrange(RADIUS,HEIGHT-RADIUS))
        vx = randrange(-5,5)
        vy = randrange(-5,5)
        while vx == 0 or vy == 0:
            vx = randrange(-5,5)
            vy = randrange(-5,5)
        self.velocity = Vector(vx,vy)

    def draw(self):
        self.center.x += self.velocity.x
        self.center.y += self.velocity.y
        for ball in TAB:
            if ball != self:
                if ball.center.distance(self.center) <= 2*RADIUS:
                    tmp = self.velocity
                    self.velocity = ball.velocity
                    ball.velocity = tmp
        if self.center.x - self.radius <= 0:
            self.velocity.x = -self.velocity.x
        if self.center.x + self.radius >= WIDTH:
            self.velocity.x = -self.velocity.x
        if self.center.y - self.radius <= 0:
            self.velocity.y = -self.velocity.y
        if self.center.y + self.radius >= HEIGHT:
            self.velocity.y = -self.velocity.y
        pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF, BLUE, self.center.getTouple(), self.radius, 0)

BallNum = 30
for i in range(BallNum):
    k = Ball()
    TAB.append(k)

while True:
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(WHITE) 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    for ball in TAB:
        ball.draw()
    pygame.display.update() 
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

This code works but not corectly: some balls are 'catched' by the bounds and others 'stick together'. I think the problem is in `Ball` class method `draw`. I will be grateful for any ideas on how to improve that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with the code you have posted which causes some of the balls to stick together, is that after they bounce off of each other, they still are in contact, so they bounce off of each other indefinitely which causes them to 'stick together'.

**To fix this problem**:

- Add in an attribute/variable which holds a reference to the ball that it last hit. I called this attribute `ball_last_hit` and I initialized it to `None`.
- Then, in the collision detection code, simply check to make sure the ball is not in contact with the ball it last hit, with an if statement like this: `if ball != self.ball_last_hit:`.
- Then, if the balls should bounce off of each other, after swapping their velocities, set `self.ball_last_hit` to `ball`.

This will solve the 'sticking together' problem between the balls, but the ball could still get 'stuck' to the wall, although it is less common. To solve this you could add in an attribute called something like `self.ignore_walls` and after each collision with a wall, set it to true, then after a certain amount of time, set it back to false, so it can collide with walls again.

Here is the fixed code:

```
import pygame,sys,math
from pygame.locals import *
from random import randrange


WIDTH = 500
HEIGHT = 500
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
RADIUS = 10
FPS = 30
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH,HEIGHT),0,32)
TAB = []

fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.display.set_caption('Animation')


class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def distance(self, A):
        return math.sqrt((A.x-self.x)**2 + (A.y-self.y)**2)
    def getTouple(self):
        return (self.x,self.y)

class Vector:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def norm(self):
        return math.sqrt(self.x**2 + self.y**2)

class Ball:
    def __init__(self):
        self.radius = RADIUS
        self.center = Point(randrange(RADIUS,WIDTH-RADIUS), randrange(RADIUS,HEIGHT-RADIUS))
        vx = randrange(-5,5)
        vy = randrange(-5,5)
        while vx == 0 or vy == 0:
            vx = randrange(-5,5)
            vy = randrange(-5,5)
        self.velocity = Vector(vx,vy)
        self.ball_last_hit = None

    def draw(self):
        self.center.x += self.velocity.x
        self.center.y += self.velocity.y

        for ball in TAB:
            if ball != self:
                if ball.center.distance(self.center) <= 2*RADIUS:
                    if ball != self.ball_last_hit:
                        tmp = self.velocity
                        self.velocity = ball.velocity
                        ball.velocity = tmp
                        self.ball_last_hit = ball

        if self.center.x - self.radius <= 0:
            self.velocity.x = -self.velocity.x
        if self.center.x + self.radius >= WIDTH:
            self.velocity.x = -self.velocity.x
        if self.center.y - self.radius <= 0:
            self.velocity.y = -self.velocity.y
        if self.center.y + self.radius >= HEIGHT:
            self.velocity.y = -self.velocity.y

        pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF, BLUE, self.center.getTouple(), self.radius, 0)

BallNum = 30
for i in range(BallNum):
    k = Ball()
    TAB.append(k)

while True:
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(WHITE) 
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    for ball in TAB:
        ball.draw()
    pygame.display.update() 
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

Note: instead of using a `temp` variable, and executing three lines of code, you can swap the balls' velocities with just one this line of code: `self.velocity, ball.velocity = ball.velocity, self.velocity`.

I hope this answer helped you, and if you have any further questions, please feel free to leave a comment below!

Edit: to get rid of the sticking to the walls, all we need to do is make sure that after a collision with the wall, the ball is not still in contact with the wall, because if it is, it will bounce against the wall indefinitely, and get 'stuck'

After changing the ball's velocity, when it collides with the wall, I just set the center of the ball to one pixel away from the wall, so it is definitely not touching the wall, and this fixed the problem for me.

Here is the new collision detection code, which goes at the end of the `draw()` method. There are just 4 new lines needed.

```
    if self.center.x - self.radius <= 0:
        self.velocity.x = -self.velocity.x
        self.center.x = self.radius + 1

    if self.center.x + self.radius >= WIDTH:
        self.velocity.x = -self.velocity.x
        self.center.x = WIDTH - self.radius - 1

    if self.center.y - self.radius <= 0:
        self.velocity.y = -self.velocity.y
        self.center.y =   self.radius + 1

    if self.center.y + self.radius >= HEIGHT:
        self.velocity.y = -self.velocity.y
        self.center.y = HEIGHT - self.radius - 1
```

Note: this simulation gets very tricky if you increase the ball number even higher, because groups of 3 balls start to collide with each other at a time, and your current code is only capable of handling collision between two balls.

Comment: your answer is very helpful.

Comment: Glad I could help! Remember to [upvote posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) which you find helpful. Thanks!

Comment: For `BallNum = 30` your code works perfect, but when I increase number of balls, for example `BallNum = 60` after some time balls stick to bounds of the screen surface

Comment: @azonips I've edited the question, to include a solution to your problem!